# Exposing obfuscated api to Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, obfuscation, nashorn

I was looking for a solution for about week now, couldn't find anything useful.

Let's say i have class like this:

```
package foo.bar;

public class Entity {
    private static int a;

    public static int b() { 
        return a; 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to expose classes like this to Nashorn? I do have a mappings for every single obfuscated field/method, it's not a problem. Also, it is an legacy api, so i cannot change it in any way.

I had an idea of writing wrappers for everything, but there's just too many classes to deal with.

EDIT: one of the possible solutions is somehow bind properties to java classes in Nashorn so that they are accessible as a static or instance members, but i yet to find a way to do it

Comment: can you try reflection ? I don't have any environment. So, I can't try

Comment: @Ravi no, reflection is not an option since there will be alot of script calls involving this api

Comment: I don't understand the problem here, can't you use the  [Nashorn API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html) to retrieve it? With something like `var entityB = Java.type("foo.bar.Entity").b();`